# Error starting thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create an UPD internet connection using SDL2_Net. And I figured I probably want that listening for data on a separate thread, so I tried creating one.
The error I get is:

```
1>e:\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(1152): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
1>          e:\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(1152) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=true,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall ListenerUDP::* )(void),void,ListenerUDP,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _V0_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          e:\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=true,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall ListenerUDP::* )(void),void,ListenerUDP,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _V0_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          e:\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(52) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=true,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall ListenerUDP::* )(void),void,ListenerUDP,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _V0_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aleksander\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\ledii - internet\ledii - internet\listenerudp.cpp(8) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__thiscall ListenerUDP::* )(void)>(_Fn)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=void (__thiscall ListenerUDP::* )(void)
1>          ]
```

The documentation says:

```
void foo() 
{
  // do stuff...
}

void bar(int x)
{
  // do stuff...
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
  std::thread second (bar,0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)

  std::cout << "main, foo and bar now execute concurrently...\n";

  // synchronize threads:
  first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
  second.join();               // pauses until second finishes

  std::cout << "foo and bar completed.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my class header:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL_net.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class ListenerUDP {
private:
    thread *threadListen;
    bool threadExit;
    vector <string> events;

    void threadLoop();

public:
    ListenerUDP();
    ~ListenerUDP();
};
```

And my class source:

```
#include "ListenerUDP.h"



ListenerUDP::ListenerUDP() {
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    threadExit = false;
    threadListen = new thread(&ListenerUDP::threadLoop);
}

ListenerUDP::~ListenerUDP() {
    printf("Disconnecting...\n");
    threadExit = true;
    threadListen->join();
}

void ListenerUDP::threadLoop() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i != -1 && !threadExit) {
        if (i++ >= 1000) {
            i = 0;
            printf("Thread simulated tick!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error if I don't make my thread a pointer!

Comment: make ```void ListenerUDP::threadLoop()``` to a static function ```static void ListenerUDP::threadLoop()```

Comment: ah, thanks. makes sense as it's being referrenced by another thread

Comment: But how can I stop it from running the loop now? It says I'm not allowed to access any of the class's not-static members, like the bool threadExit.

Comment: I solved it by passing a pointer to "this" as an ListenerUDP* as an argument. Is that a decent solution? Or is it very inefficient or ugly?

Comment: pass this is also a solution. and for your requirement, it is a decent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pass class member function to std::thread, it requires a class instance. so you can pass **this** as a parameter to std::thread constructor.

```
threadListen = new thread(&ListenerUDP::threadLoop, this);
```